# SPATSTAT code for molecular pattern for a image

Tags: image, function, spatstat

Can't interpret X as a point pattern, ask for help!

> library(imager)
> library(spatstat)
>
> ## Read image
>
> img <- load.image("C:/Users/yyan2/Documents/Dec 21/F10F.jpg")
> img_gray <- grayscale(img)
> threshold <- 0.5 # adjust this value as needed
> img_thresh <- img_gray > threshold
> class(img_thresh) # convert the binary image to a matrix
> [1] "pixset"       "imager_array" "logical"
> binary_image <- as.im(matrix(as.numeric(img_thresh), nrow = nrow(img_thresh),

- ```
                           ncol = ncol(img_thresh))) # convert to binary image
  ```

> image_window <- owin(c(1, ncol(img_thresh)), c(1, nrow(img_thresh)))
> point_pattern <- as.ppp(binary_image, window = image_window)
> Error in as.ppp.default(binary_image, window = image_window) :
> Can't interpret X as a point pattern

I have tried all kinds of function that I know, it won't work. so frustrating

Answer (score 1):

The function `as.ppp` (and in general any conversion function `as.xxx`) is designed to convert data from one format to another format which represents the same information.

It seems that you want to convert a binary pixel image into a point pattern. But these are different kinds of information, so exactly what do you want to do?

1. Do you want every pixel that is `TRUE` in the binary image to become a separate point in the point pattern?
2. Or does the binary image contain blobs/islands/clusters of TRUE pixels and you want the centre of each island to be a separate point in the point pattern?

It's unclear what is intended, since you did not provide a working example. Neither I nor the computer can guess what you want.

If your intention is (1) above, then use `pixelcentres`, e.g.

```
P <- pixelcentres(binaryimage)
```

If your intention is (2) above, use `connected.im` to identify the islands, then extract them and compute a suitable midpoint, e.g.

```
Labelled <- connected(binaryimage)
Islands <- tiles(tess(image=Labelled))
Centres <- lapply(Islands, centroid.owin)
xy <- t(sapply(Centres, as.numeric))
P <- as.ppp(xy, W=Window(binaryimage))
```